# Does Microsoft allows access to built in method definitions?

Tags: .net, methods

As a programmer mostly we use .NET framework as a tool that gives us a lot of use full features. ".NET" itself contains classes and classes contain Methods(that we use). 

But my question is can we view the method definitions? Does Microsoft allows us? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public member definitions are all visible in VS easily, either by using the object explorer or F12 on a framework member. Non-public members are not visible by default. However, this is just the member signature, not the implementation.

You can disassemble Microsoft DLLs for reading purposes and they also made the framework source available for debugging / reading.

Please refer to:

- [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For most of it, yes, you can download the reference sources: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx. It's especially useful for debugging purposes.

Apparently some parts are not included (maybe sensitive stuff that has to do with security), last I heard.

Comment: I'm assuming by 'method definitions' you mean the actual definition of the methods in the source, not just the method signatures.